# C# awaitable problems

Tags: c#, exception, asynchronous, async-await

`documents` is a `IDictionary<string, string>` where the parameters are `<filename, fileUrl>`

`DocumentHandler.Download()` returns a `Task<Memorystram>`

This code works:

```
foreach (var x in documents.Keys)
    {
        var result = await DocumentHandler.Download(new Uri(documents[x]));
        // other code
    }
```

however it rund synchronously.

In order to run it all async i wrote this code:

```
var keys =
documents.Keys.Select(async x =>
    {
        return Tuple.Create(x, await DocumentHandler.Download(new Uri(documents[x])));
    });
await Task.WhenAll(keys);
foreach (var item in keys)
{
    var tpl = item.Result;
    // other code
}
```

It doesn't work, it crashes without showing an exception on the last line `var tpl = item.Result;` Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `keys` variable will create a *new* set of tasks every time you evaluate it... so after waiting for the first set of tasks to complete, you're iterating over a new set of unfinished tasks. The simple fix for this is to add a call to `ToList()`:

```
var keys = documents
    .Keys
    .Select(async x => Tuple.Create(x, await DocumentHandler.Download(new Uri(documents[x]))))
    .ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(keys);
foreach (var item in keys)
{
    var tpl = item.Result;
    // other code
}
```

Comment: correct but also notice that tuple does not have Result property ;) so OP meant compile time error at `var tpl = item.Result;`. also i think `keys` is type of `List<Tuple<string,Task<Memorystram>>>` so you cant await on them too.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: The OP isn't trying to use the `Result` property of `Tuple` - they're using the `Result` property of `Task<Tuple<string, ...>>`. An async lambda expression will create a `Func<Task<...>>`. If the OP were running into a compile-time error, they wouldn't say it was "crashing without showing an exception".

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: Also note that it wouldn't be a `Tuple<string, Task<MemoryStream>>` because the async lambda expression is awaiting the result of `DocumentHandler.Download`.

Comment: @Emaborsa: Do you understand that LINQ is lazy? That every time you iterate over the `keys` variable in your code, you're creating new tasks? If not, you should really revisit the basics of LINQ and lazy execution.

Comment: oh. i got it. thanks for explanation. forgive me!  ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes i undestand it, but i thought that `await Task.WhenAll(keys)` would execute them

Comment: @Emaborsa: Yes, that will create one sequence of tasks, and wait for them all to finish. You're then iterating over a sequence of *new* tasks, which haven't had time to run yet.

Comment: @JonSkeet ok i got it. Thanks